# Linear Transformations - question

Tags: linear-transformations

T is linear transformation 
$$T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$$

$$T(1,9,9)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    9 & 0  \\
    12 & 82  
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$T(0,1,9)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    9 & 81   
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$T(0,0,1)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    9 & 9  \\
    93 & 811  
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

need to find $A\in\text{Im}(T)$ such that $$|A|=-441$$

Soo far I found  that:
$$T(1,0,0)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    657 & 639  \\
    6627 & 57745
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$T(0,1,0)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -81 & -80\\
    -828 & -7218
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and we know that :
$$T(0,0,1)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    9 & 9  \\
    93 & 811  
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find $T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0), T(0,0,1)$. Simply solve

$$\left|\alpha T(1,9,9)+\beta T(0,1,9)+\gamma T(0,0,1)\right|=-144$$

for either $\alpha,\beta$ or $\gamma$, and you get all the possible solutions.

If you need just one example of a solution, as opposed to the full space of solutions, it can be simpler still, for example find $\alpha$ such that
$$\left|\alpha T(1,9,9)\right|=-144$$

Comment: so finding $T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0), T(0,0,1)$ isn't helping at all? it took me a while

Comment: + how do you solve this?

Comment: It is a good idea in general, if you actually need to know an expression for $T$. Just in this case, you don't need that.

Comment: Write out the determinant. It should be at worst a second-order equation in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

Comment: $$738*a^2-9*b^2+717*a*b+6462*c^2+7929*a*c+555*b*c$$
I replaced alpha beta gama because I don't know how to write them here. now what we do?

Comment: set it equal to -144, solve for $a$

Comment: How to solve such a complicated thing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: oh ok I just take b and c as parameters ok

Comment: it didn't work out

Comment: can you help me solve it?( if you can give solution will realy help)
ty!